# Выполнение строки без eval PHP

Tags: php

Возможно ли реализовать такую конструкцию?:

```
$value = "MyClass";
$class = new $value;
$value2 = '->';
$class$value2MyMethod;
```

И еще интересует один вопрос, более отдаленный от темы. Что означает ${}?

Comment: с `$value2` вряд ли можно так провернуть. Однако зачем вам хранить `->` в переменной если можно написать вот так сразу: `$class->$MyMethod;` ?

Comment: @Filipp Mustang я там чутка добавил в ответ

Comment: Со стрелкой, скорее всего, плохой пример. Мне нужно писать название массивов, функции необычными методами. Например, возьмем isset. Можно ли задать функции isset псевдоним? Интересный ответ у @splash58, мне нужно на подобии того, только с функцией.

Comment: смотрим продолжение ответа

Answer (score 3, accepted):

давно бы просто попробовали

```
class MyClass {

public function __construct() {
  echo 'а то ж';
}
}
$value = "MyClass";
$class = new $value;
```

[вот тут](https://eval.in/547736)

UPD:

стрелку не получится - это конструкция языка, а про метод, так можно

```
class MyClass {

public function __construct() {
  echo 'а то ж';
}
public function metod() {
  echo 'а это метод';
}
}
$value = "MyClass";
$class = new $value;
$m = 'metod';

$a = [$class, $m];
$a();
```

[демо](https://eval.in/547754)

UPD2:

две строчки кода быстрее написать, чем спрашивать. расширяем пример

```
$p = 'print_r';
$p($a);
```

[смотрим](https://eval.in/547766)

Comment: Ух. интересно. А вот не знал, что так можно метод вызвать. А где об этом написано? Напишите ссылку прям в ответе пожалуйста

Comment: Алексей, я не знаю, где про это написано, я тут в перерывах в работе учу php на SO :) где-то видел. правда, не в таком контексте, но работает, оказывается

Comment: ну кстати ещё можно вызывать с помощью этой функции http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php типа call_user_func(array(new $value, "method"));

Comment: Во, Василий, такое я и видел. вот и решил попробовать :)

Comment: И еще, последний вопрос. Можно ли таким способом еще получить значение из массива, ведь получается функции или методу ничего нельзя передать

Comment: @FilippMustang посмотрите то, что написал Василий http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php  .... там можно передавать параметры. Однако и то, что предложил splash58 вполне можно исполнить с параметрами...вы бы хоть попытались бы `class MyClass {

public function __construct() {
  echo 'а то ж';
}
public function metod($var) {
  echo 'а это метод'.' '.$var;
}
}
$value = "MyClass";
$class = new $value;
$m = 'metod';

$a = [$class, $m];
$a('Вот оно че, михалыч');`